# MySQL- Fetch data from multiple tables by matching the reference

Tags: mysql, database, join, phpmyadmin, relationship

I tried using the join query to fetch data from different tables. But it is returning no results even though there is data.

The Student Master table has details about the student. The student's roll number is the primary key in this table. The roll number is added in all results table (i.e. first_term_results, second_term_results etc.,) to refer.

So, to fetch the student details, his first and second term results, I am using the following query which is not giving the intended results. I am trying to fetch the details that match the roll_no.

```
SELECT a.*, b .*,c.*
FROM student_master AS a
INNER JOIN first_term_results AS b
INNER JOIN second_term_results AS c
ON a.roll_no = b.roll_no = c.roll_no
WHERE a.roll_no = '53'
AND b.roll_no='53'
AND c.roll_no = '53'
```

Could someone help me to correct this query to get the results I am expecting ?.Also please let me know if I you are not clear. I can explain.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after formating your query to something readable I get this

```
SELECT a.*, b .*,c.* 
FROM   student_master AS a 
  INNER JOIN first_term_results AS b 
  INNER JOIN second_term_results AS c ON a.roll_no = b.roll_no = c.roll_no 
WHERE   a.roll_no = '53' 
AND     b.roll_no='53'
AND     c.roll_no = '53'
```

and it looks a bit strange to me,
I would go for something like this

```
SELECT a.*, b .*,c.* 
FROM   student_master AS a 
  INNER JOIN first_term_results AS b on a.roll_no = b.roll_no 
  INNER JOIN second_term_results AS c ON a.roll_no = c.roll_no 
WHERE   a.roll_no = '53'
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your query to

```
SELECT a.*, b.*,c.*
FROM student_master AS a
INNER JOIN first_term_results AS b ON a.roll_no = b.roll_no
INNER JOIN second_term_results AS c ON a.roll_no = c.roll_no
WHERE a.roll_no = '53'
```

Answer (score 1):

This should fit your wishes:

```
SELECT a.*, b .*,c.*
FROM student_master AS a
LEFT JOIN first_term_results AS b ON(a.roll_no = b.roll_no)
LEFT JOIN second_term_results AS c ON( a.roll_no = c.roll_no)
WHERE a.roll_no = '53'
```

did you check if there are errors returned by the drivers?

Comment: All the answers above are working fine. Thanks alot guys.

Comment: this answer is a bit different because you also get a result if there is no entry in the second_term_results table. so you also get results for students they don't have written a second term.#

Comment: @BigB (same for first_term_result). see the difference? there are left joins instead of inner joins. I don't know if you want that or not. you have to decide

Comment: I haven't tried LEFT JOIN. I will try it now. But what difference it makes. I can see the roll_no field is repeated. How can I restrict to one ?

Comment: I don't know what you meant. repeated? it's the same at inner join and left join. compare with the other solutions. the difference: there is no need for a record in first_term_results or second_term_results with roll_no=53. if there is no record this fields will be null. in the case you are using INNER JOIN. There has to be an entry in each table for each roll_no. but perhaps. a person only wrote first_term and not second_term. then there is no result in second_term and you get no result in the resultset of your statement

Comment: All 3 tables have the field roll_no, so if you write a.*, b.*, c.* than this field will offcourse be repeated 3 times.  If you do not want that then you will have to write fieldnames in stead of *  Example: a.field1, a.field2, a.roll_no, b.field3, c.field3, and so on...